# How to handle the click in the canvas on a certain layer?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Here is my code:

```
var background = new LibCanvas('#canv');
 var planet = background.createLayer('planet');
 var mouse = planet.listenMouse();
  mouse.addEvent('click', function () {
    //code
  });
```

By clicking on the layer is not something that should be.

If I doing this:

```
var background = new LibCanvas('#canv');
 var planet = background.createLayer('planet');
 var mouse = planet.listenMouse();
var info=mouse.mouse;
  info.addEvent('click', function () {
    //code
  });
```

Clicking work out, but it works off and on in the background

Comment: As you can see from your second code -you should address the mouse as `mouse = planet.listenMouse().mouse`.

Comment: Click on all the canvas work out, but I need to be precisely that in a certain place worked.

Answer (score 0):

You should bind your event to element, not to layer. Look at that example: http://libcanvas.github.com/ui/button.html

You just need add something like that and everything will works fine:

```
button.addEvent( 'click', function (e) {
    trace(e.offset);
});
```

Also, in this code `listenMouse` returns `this`, so result is `mouse === planet`. `layer.mouse` is link to one object at all layers.

```
var planet = background.createLayer('planet');
var mouse = planet.listenMouse();
```